# FlatMap and subjects - how to avoid duplicating subscribers?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, subject-observer, behaviorsubject

Let's say I have the following code:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject2 = BehaviorSubject.create();
subject.
        doOnNext(number -> subject2.onNext(number)).
        flatMap(number -> subject2).
        subscribe(number -> System.out.println("Number " + number));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    subject.onNext(i);
}
```

The output it produces is:

```
Number 0
Number 1
Number 1
Number 2
Number 2
Number 2
Number 3
Number 3
Number 3
Number 3
Number 4
Number 4
Number 4
Number 4
Number 4
```

And on and on.

I understand why it happens - it's because every time `flatMap` is called, new subscriber is added to `subject2`.

The question is - how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

try `switchMap` instead of `flatMap`.

`switchMap` is only ever subscribed to the last `Observable` it receives. It unsubscribes from all previously subscribed `Observable`s.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchMap

Answer (score 1):

You can limit subject2 to one element inside `flatMap` like this:

`flatMap(number -> subject2.first())`

Code

```
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject2 = BehaviorSubject.create();
    subject.
            doOnNext(number -> subject2.onNext(number)).
            flatMap(number -> subject2.first()).
            subscribe(number -> System.out.println("Number " + number));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        subject.onNext(i);
    }
```

produces output which does not contain duplicates